# Multiple joins using IQueryable in lightswitch

Tags: asp.net, iqueryable, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using lightswitch and i have to join 3 tables in my query. Table A join Table B join table C where tableC.id == 10

partial void Query2_PreprocessQuery(int? dept, ref IQueryable query)
    {

```
    query = query.Join(Employee_Personal_Infoes, b => b.Employee_Personal_Info1.Emp_id, (b));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you add **relationships** between your tables, you shouldn't ever need to do **manual joins**. You would then just use the **navigation properties** that get created when you add the relationships.

Second, you can't change the **shape** of the entity in a query, or return a set of **different entities**. If your query is based say on a *Customer* entity, you can't return a query of *CustomerAdresses*, or a *Client* entity from that query. The query can only return a **filtered** set of the **same entity** that the query is based on.

Does that make sense?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170173/accessing-static-variable-over-different-projects-in-lightswitch please check this question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure why you've referred me to that link. But the answer to the question you've asked there is that you *can't* share static variables using the Common project in the manner described. The why is a little complicated to put in a comment here. Don't worry, it's a common mistake to make.